# Initialize an empty nested struct using a function

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have to initialize tCoworking coworking by implementing init_coworking function that is declared at the end.

```
/* Constants *********************************************************/
#define nWorkSpaces 50
#define unlimited 2000

/* Types *************************************************************/
typedef enum {tableFlex, tableFix, officeFix} rate;
typedef char string[55];

typedef struct {
    int reservationId;
    float monthPayment;
} tContractAnnex;

typedef struct {
    int id;
    string name;
    int discount;
} tPartner;

typedef struct {
    int id;
    float surface;
    rate rateType;
} tWorkspace;

typedef struct {
    int partnerId;
    int month;
    int year;
    tContractAnnex annex;
} tContract;

typedef struct {
    tWorkspace workSpace[nWorkSpaces];
    tContract contract[unlimited];
    tPartner partner[unlimited];
} tCoworking;

/* Function declaration */

void init_coworking(tCoworking *coworking);
```

As you can see the problem I have is that tCoworking is a nested struct with array of stucts as data types..
So far I'm doing this in order to initialize it but it must be a better way to do it.

```
void init_coworking(tCoworking *coworking){
coworking = malloc(sizeof(tCoworking));

 coworking->partner[0].id = 0;
 coworking->partner[0].discount = 0;
 strcpy(coworking->partner[0].name, "");
 
 coworking->workSpace[0].id = 0;
 coworking->workSpace[0].rateType = 0;
 coworking->workSpace[0].surface = 0;
 
 
 coworking->contract[0].partnerId = 0;
 coworking->contract[0].year = 0;
 coworking->contract[0].month = 0;
 coworking->contract[0].annex.monthPayment = 0;
 coworking->contract[0].annex.reservationId = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void init_coworking(tCoworking *coworking) {
 coworking && memset( coworking, 0, sizeof( tCoworking ) );
}
```

`memset` initializes a block of memory - of specifiable length - to a single byte value. Your example indicates that you desire zero-initialization of the entire object, so `memset` serves this purpose well.
`NULL`-check your input argument.

I recommend you **not** `malloc` or `calloc` in your function because your function signature implies that the caller is the owner of the `tCoworking`. If you `malloc` within your `init_coworking()` function, then you'll have created a new heap-allocated instance of a `tCoworking` with no clear ownership. You can try keep track of newly-allocated objects in some type of container, but that's going far beyond the scope of your question -- keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use `calloc`. Like `malloc` it allocates memory for you but it also sets all the memory to zero.

However - **more important is** that your current function doesn't make sense. The memory you allocate is simply lost. The caller of `init_coworking` will never get the allocated and initialized memory.

Either you should:

1. Not do any `malloc`(or `calloc`)

or

2. Return the `malloc`ed pointer.

Since the prototype suggest that you get a `tCoworking` pointer, the most likely thing is that it's already allocated (in some way), i.e. you want option 1.

So just do:

```
void init_coworking(tCoworking *coworking){   // NO malloc
    memset(coworking, 0, sizeof(tCoworking));
}
```

In case you only want the first array member set to zero (like your code indicates) you may get a little performance improvement by:

```
void init_coworking(tCoworking *coworking){   // NO malloc
    memset(&coworking->partner[0], 0, sizeof(coworking->partner[0]));
    ... similar for the other arrays ...
}
```

but I doubt that's worth the trouble...